# Using numeric_limits::max() in constant expressions

Tags: c++, std, constexpr, numeric-limits

I would like to define inside a class a constant which value is the maximum possible int. Something like this:

```
class A
{
    ...
    static const int ERROR_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    ...
}
```

This declaration fails to compile with the following message:

> numeric.cpp:8: error: 'std::numeric_limits::max()' cannot appear in a constant-expression
>   numeric.cpp:8: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

I understand why this doesn't work, but two things look weird to me:

1. It seems to me a natural decision to use the value in constant expressions. Why did the language designers decide to make *max()* a function thus not allowing this usage?
2. The spec claims in 18.2.1 that

   > For all members declared static const in the numeric_limits template, specializations shall define these values in such a way that they are usable as integral constant expressions.

   Doesn't it mean that I should be able to use it in my scenario and doesn't it contradict the error message?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use climits http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/

Comment: @aaa: But `climits` won't play nice with templates.

Comment: @Uncle unfortunately.  in principle can wrap defines in templates, some work but doable. or boost integer_traits I think provides them already : `integer_traits <>::const_max/const_min`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While the current standard lacks support here, for integral types [Boost.IntegerTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/traits.html) gives you the compile time constants `const_min` and `const_max`.

The problem arises from *§9.4.2/4*:

> If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19). In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions.

Note that it adds:

> The member shall still be defined in a name- space scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

As others already mentioned `numeric_limit`s `min()` and `max()` simply aren't integral constant expressions, i.e. compile time constants.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like a bit of a defect...

In C++0x, `numeric_limits` will have everything marked with `constexpr`, meaning you will be able to use `min()` and `max()` as compile-time constants.

Comment: For those wondering, apparently support for this was added in Visual Studio 2015. Now if I could just get IT to update from 2013...

Answer (score 14):

You want:

```
#include <limits>

struct A {
static const int ERROR_VALUE;
}; 

const int A::ERROR_VALUE = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Put the class/struct in a header and the definition in a .cpp file.

Comment: can ERR_VALUE defined as above be used as template argument?

Comment: What is the difference between initialization inside the class and outside? I know that I can initialize consts inside the class with integral values. Also, I must have at least one instance of such a class, right? Otherwise the compiler might decide not to initialize it?

Comment: Tagging along: isn't there any library here (perhaps boost) that redefine those values so that they can be used in metatemplate programming ? It would make sense to have them at our disposal at compile-time...

Comment: @aaa No, but that's not what he was asking about.

Comment: @FireAphis No, you don't need a class instance - it's static!

Comment: @Matt http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/integer_traits.hpp  integer_traits<>::const_max member does it.

@Neil  I was just curious

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't contradict, because `max` is not defined `static const`. It's just a static member function. Functions can't be const, and static member functions can't have a const attached at the very right either.

There is also a `double max()` in the double version of the limits, and in C++03 it wouldn't work to say `static double const max = ...`. So to be consistent, `max()` is a function for all versions of the limit template.

Now, it's known that `max()` not being able to be used like that is bad, and C++0x already solves it by making it a `constexpr` function, allowing your proposed usage.

Answer (score 2):

- I will try to answer you as  much as I understood from your question:

1- If you want a static const int in your program to be initialized with a function:

```
int Data()
{
 return rand();
}

class A
{
public :
    static const int ee;
};
const int A::ee=Data();
```

This works on VS 2008

2- If you want to get max and min number for a given data type, then use these definitions
INT_MAX, INT_MIN, LONG_MAX and so on..

3- If however you need to use these wrt template type, then
hard code the templates yourself

```
template<>
int MaxData()
{
 return INT_MAX;
}
```

and

```
template<>
long MaxData()
{
 return LONG_MAX ;
}
```

and call them like this

```
int y=MaxData<int>();
```

4- and if you are only dealing with binary represented types only, then use this:

```
template <class T>
T MaxData(){
    return ~(1<<((sizeof(T)*8)-1));
}
```

and this

```
template <class T>
T MinData(){
    return (1<<((sizeof(T)*8)-1));
}
```

Hope this can help you..

Comment: Instead of numerical value 8, rather use CHAR_BIT macro from climits (limits.h).