# Why are numeric_limit<T>::min/max not a constants?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is std::numeric_limits<T>::max() a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766272/why-is-stdnumeric-limitstmax-a-function)

I was wondering if someone could explain the reasoning behind why `std::numeric_limit<T>::min` and `max` are functions and not constants?

Furthermore, I'd like to know what techniques can be used to make use of the min/max values as part of template parameters, eg:

```
template<unsigned long long max>
class foo
{
public:
   void boo() { std::cout << max << std::endl; }
};

.
.
.

foo<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()> f;
f.boo();
```

Comment: ...and regarding the second part of your question, about instantiating templates, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738435/using-numeric-limitsmax-in-constant-expressions/2738576#2738576

Comment: @John: Thanks for those answers, but i was hoping for a solution not based on Boost as I don't have access to it in the project I'm currently working on.

Comment: Well then you may want to use Aaron's solution below.

Answer (score 5):

Fall back on good old C!

```
foo< INT_MAX > f;
```

or even

```
const int my_int_max = INTMAX;
foo< my_int_max > f;
```

Works for me on g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5