# C++ numeric_limits constant and function

Tags: c++, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is std::numeric_limits<T>::max() a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766272/why-is-stdnumeric-limitstmax-a-function)

why `numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity` is a const value and `numeric_limits<T>::infinity` is not? why make `numeric_limits<T>::infinity` a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because things like `float`, `double` or `UDT` *static const* values cannot be initialized in class and need an external definition. In simple words they need a *memory location*, while *static const integral* values do not (as long as a pointer/reference to them is not taken).

In **C++11** these functions should be declared `constexpr`, which defeats any shortcoming you may be seeing from the fact that they are functions instead of constants.