# C++ recursive template type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, template-meta-programming

I'm interested in learning a little about template meta-programming. In the code below I'm attempting to find an unsigned integral type large enough to hold N bits, specified at compile time, using some template recursion.

```
template <typename T>
struct NextIntegralType
{
};

template <>
struct NextIntegralType<void>
{
    typedef unsigned char type;
};

template <>
struct NextIntegralType<unsigned char>
{
    typedef unsigned short type;
};

...More type 'iteration' here...

template<size_t BITS, typename T>
struct FindIntegralType2
{
    typedef std::conditional<BITS <= sizeof(typename T::type)*8, T, FindIntegralType2<BITS, NextIntegralType<typename T::type>>> _type;
    typedef typename _type::type type;
};

template<size_t BITS>
struct FindIntegralType
{
    typedef typename FindIntegralType2<BITS, NextIntegralType<void>>::type type;
};
```

When I declare a variable and assign an integral value to it...

```
FindIntegralType<15>::type test(4000);
```

I get the following:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘FindIntegralType2<15u, NextIntegralType<unsigned char> >::FindIntegralType2(int)’
note: candidates are:
note: constexpr FindIntegralType2<15u, NextIntegralType<unsigned char> >::FindIntegralType2()
note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
note: constexpr FindIntegralType2<15u, NextIntegralType<unsigned char> >::FindIntegralType2(const FindIntegralType2<15u, NextIntegralType<unsigned char> >&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const FindIntegralType2<15u, NextIntegralType<unsigned char> >&’
```

It seems like my recursion isn't 'unwinding'. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Note: I'm using **GCC 4.6**.

**EDIT:**

I found a post that I missed before:

[Automatically pick a variable type big enough to hold a specified number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038797/automatically-pick-a-variable-type-big-enough-to-hold-a-specified-number)

Which points to an answer in boost (where they always are):

[boost_integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html)

This should solve both my practical need and intellectual curiosity.

Comment: @mfontanini Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `_type::type` evaluates to `std::conditional<...>::type`, not `FindIntegralType2<...>::type`. Change it to `typedef typename _type::type::type type;` (too much `type` x_X). This should solve your problem.