# Conditional-Operator in Constant Expression

Tags: c++, c, conditional-operator, constant-expression

I tried the following code snippet with MSVC 10, where it works fine.

```
enum
{
  FOO = (sizeof(void*) == 8 ? 10 : 20)
};

int main()
{
  return FOO;
}
```

What I would like to know is: Does the C++ Standard (preferably C++98) allow me to use the conditional-operator in a constant expression when all operands are constant expressions, or is this a Microsoft quirk/extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly valid and sensible standard C++.

The ternary conditional operator forms an *expression*, and the expression is a constant expression if its operands are.

The standard reference is C++11 5.19/2:

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* [...]

Note that by 5.16, ternary conditional expressions are one type of *conditional-expressions*. Other types are things like `2 == 3`.

Comment: Could you explain to me how this is defined in the standard? Apparently e.g. (C99 6.6/6) describes integer constant expressions, but it doesn't say much about operators.

Comment: @mooware: I thought you're asking about C++? C is quite a bit different when it comes to constant expressions (at least C89). I'm happy to let someone else dig up a C reference.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about C++, but that was the first reference I found here on SO. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your answer.

Comment: perfect answer to justify Maxim's answer in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7039269/893406